# Is NSPortMessage in the iOS API?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, foundation

I am trying to write a demo according to Thread Programming Guide about run loops.
When I implement NSPortDelegate's `- (void)handlePortMessage:(NSPortMessage *)portMessage;` method it prompts an error:

> Receiver type 'NSPortMessage' for instance message is a forward declaration

So I try to import by "Foundation/NSPortMessage.h", after which it says:

> Foundation/NSPortMessage.h file not found.

So I wonder whether we can use NSPortMesssage in iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSPortMessage` doesn't seem to be in the iOS documentation so is presumably a private API. Xcode does code completion of `NSPortMessage` for me when I try to use it, presumably because of the forward declaration. However, if I ask Xcode to show me the definition of `NSPortMessage` it says the symbol is not found which would confirm that it is a private API.

The class exists in the Objective-C Runtime on my iPhone 4s so it is on the device.  However `NSPortMessage` allows inter-process communication which I assume would be against the iOS sandboxing security.  Perhaps it will work for inter-thread communications though.

I certainly wouldn't try and use it in an app that is intended for the App Store.

Comment: do you means we can not configure a port-based input source for Thread's runloop in iOS?

Comment: I have no idea! I haven't tried to use `NSPortMessage` on iOS or OS X.  My answer is based on a quick search of the iOS documentation, the iOS headers and the classes that are actually loaded into the Objective-C runtime on my phone.  The class is there and it will possibly work if you take the `NSPortMessage` header declarations from the OS X SDK and import it into your iOS app.  However, it seems pretty clear that Apple have removed `NSPortMessage` from the iOS SDK, so it would be considered a private API.  The use of private APIs would get an app rejected from the App Store.

Comment: I see... why the thread programming gride about NSPortMessage is in iOS library...

Comment: It could well be a mistake that it is in the guide, it could also be a mistake that the NSPortMessage header has been removed.  You could submit a radar and see what happens. Either the guide is wrong or the headers are wrong so Apple should really fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the iOS version of distributed object programming guide and certain APIs are also deprecated, it seems that all stuff related to port-based input source are discouraged to be used for iOS development. But setting up a port-based channel to communicate between threads using Core Foundation function still be an available choice.